# Configuring a working Nginx reverse proxy caching

Tags: nginx, caching, reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx that works as a reverse proxy for a Node.js application (complete configuration https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BNGm227msh/)

Cache path and size is defined as

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=socket_io_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m;
proxy_temp_path /var/tmp/nginx;
```

And cache is applied only for a very specific page

```
location /socket.io/socket.io.js {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:3030;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.________.com;
    proxy_cache socket_io_cache; # Enable caching
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1d; # Cache valid for 1 day
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504; # Serve stale cache if errors occur
}
```

But I see no file written in `proxy_cache_path` and `proxy_temp_path` no caching in the event of 502 error.

I suppose to see cached content in directory `/var/cache/nginx` which stay totally empty and a performance improvement and I expect the cached content served in the event of 502 error (Node.js service switched off)

Any hint?